# Trying to avoid multiple layout levels

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am making a layout for a row in a list. One of the columns consists of "work Hours", which takes data from the database in 2 parts: start and finish. I am using a cursor loader to  get the data into the UI. So my question is what is the best way to combine the data of both start and finish into a format like 12:00~4:00 if the 2 times are stored separately? I've thought about putting another linear layout, but it seems like a waste. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

This is my Loader callbacks, pretty standard I think.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    String[] projection = Columns.getColumns(RawContract.PARAM_SIWORKDAYS);

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(mContext,
            BidProvider.CONTENT_URI_SIWORKDAYS, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

And I'm using it like this

```
private void fillData() {

    String[] from = new String[] { Columns.COLUMN_WORKDATE,
            Columns.COLUMN_DAYCHARGE, Columns.COLUMN_TEMPERATURE,
            Columns.COLUMN_WORKFROMHR, Columns.COLUMN_WORKTOHR,
            Columns.COLUMN_WEATHER, Columns.COLUMN_CREATEDBY,
            Columns.COLUMN_CREATEDDATE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contractor, R.id.contract_num, R.id.title,
            R.id.value, R.id.status, R.id.dept_name, R.id.start, R.id.close };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.contract_row, null, from,
            to, 0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

So I guess what I'm getting at is that I never manually pull the data from the cursor, so I'm not sure what the best way to put those two pieces of data together is.

Comment: You have a `ListView` that's being populated from a `Cursor`; every row has a starttime - finished time in it? I'm not quite sure if that's what you're asking... For clarity can you post your adapter and how you're getting your cursor into the `ListView`?

Comment: yeah, so every row has a starttime finishtime stored in separate columns and I was wondering what the best way to put those together is

Comment: When you pull them out of the database, I assume you're putting them into an object (your data model, or something) and your cursor is returning a model, and not just the individual column?

Comment: the cursor returns the columns as columns and the data is put into objects locally

Comment: So for every row, you're getting an array of columns. If you're getting the data out in that sort of format I'm not sure of the question. You just have to get your adapter properly display the array of columns you'll get from your adapter when you override the adapter's `getView`

Comment: ah sorry I'm a little confused myself. Let me try to clarify, so I am trying to align the TextViews of these columns to those of a header that labels each column in the UI, and each column takes equal space. I did this by using a linear layout with weight=1 for each view, and I was wondering how to get the starttime, a ~ and the end time in an equal space as the other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is better to use custom CursorAdapter with ViewHolder.

```
private static class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
        holder.startFinishTimeView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.startFinishTimeView);
        holder.content = v.findViewById(R.id.content);
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.startFinishTimeView.setText(<past here your formated time from Cursor>);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView startFinishTimeView;
        View content;
    }
}
```

Comment: hm this looks interesting. I'm a little confused though, where does it get the 2 separate column items?

Comment: Her <past here your formated time from Cursor> you can take every columns, what you need. Like this:
cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Columns.COLUMN_CREATEDBY)